# Array referenced in HTML not found within JS

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

Been tasked with altering a few things within a LWC. This involves altering an array. This array is referenced within the HTML of the component, however never referenced within the JS, thus a bit hard to track down. The name given to the array is quite generic making me think that I overlooked something simple. I'll be sure to post a snip of the HTML below, you can spot the loop towards the end of the snip of code. Thanks in advance for your time.

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Tactic Summary">
        <div class="componentBorder">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col">
                <lightning-input class="slds-p-left_xx-large" type="checkbox" data-field="checkbox" label="Show Events with available Seats" onchange={handleChange} checked></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
            </div>
        </div><br/>
        <div class="slds-table--header-fixed_container" style="height:300px;">
        <div class="slds-scrollable_y" style="height:100%;">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table--header-fixed">
            ...
            <template for:each={data} for:item="itm">
                    <tr key={itm.TacticContactId}>
                    </tr>
            </template>
        </table>
    ...
</template>
```

JS

Unfortunately due to the nature of the problem, I need to share either all or the majority of the accompanied js. With the character limit, it is not natively possible within this body so the js can be seen on codeshare via the following link. Sorry for the inconvenience.

https://codeshare.io/kmgvrY

Comment: You'd have to include the JS for us to have a chance of helping you.

Comment: Just added the JS. Though it was not possible natively due to the character limit. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined as:

```
@track data = [];
```

And used in `wireBlastData` at:

```
this.data = data;
```

I found this manually, but a good rule of thumb is that a variable is set with `this.variableName`, so that's a good place to start.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. I resulted to Ctrl+F to find it and that certainly did not narrow down the search. I'll be following the wire to solve the problem. Thank you very much for your time.